# OrientDB low performance in query with LUCENE and OR expression

Tags: orientdb

I have a graph database with 1.000.000 vertex. 
When I run this query: 
[image]

it work well but look at this:

[image]

The OR should not affect the performance but it does.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that the second query is doing a full scan and matching all the records against the two conditions.

Try to execute and EXPLAIN of the queries and see the difference.

We are working hard to make it much better in v 3.0

Comment: I solved in this way:
select expand($c) let $a = (select from SimpleVertex where s lucene "*su*"), $b = (select from #23:4245712), $c = unionall($a, $b)

in  4.861 sec. Still 4x slow than the big query result. Perhaps the union process.